# Pass function output to component where it's being called?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the response of the API in a component where I make the request.

I have two files, one is the screen and the other is the file that contains all the functions (api calls) to avoid messy code.

In my `Login.js`, I want to avoid making a redirect after pressing the button "Log In," but I don't know how to do the redirect depending on the response of the api. That's why my current code looks like this:

```
const loginHandler = async (values) => {
        setLoading(true);
        loginRequest({ values })
        await navigate('/main'); <-- I want to execute this line depending on what "loginRequest" returns        
        await setLoading(false);
    }
```

Inside my `api.js` I have the following function:

```
export function loginRequest({values}){
    axios.post('http://localhost/api/auth/applogin', {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password
    }).then((res) => {
        Cookies.set('token', res.data.access_token)
        console.log('logged in successfully.');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

How can I pass the server response (in this case, `res`) to `Login.js` when I call this function?

Comment: You can't await `loginRequest` if it's not returning a promise. Why not pass success/failure callbacks into the function?

Comment: @DBS okay, just removed the `await`, thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your `api.js`, change async function with try catch

```
export async function loginRequest({values}){
  try {
    const result = await axios.post('http://localhost/api/auth/applogin', {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password
    })
    Cookies.set('token', res.data.access_token)
    return result; // return data from function
  } catch (err) {
     console.log(err)
  }  
}
```

Then in your `Login.js` modify `loginRequest` to this

```
const result = await loginRequest({ values }); // api response data
```

Comment: in Login.js I have `loginHandler` how should that one look like? - and how do I even call `result` within the handler?

Comment: either you pass `result` as `loginHandler` parameter or create new state for `result`